# How to alter fragments visibility on main activity

Tags: android

In android I am trying to move more activities into one (refactor code and I try to replace set of activities with fragments), but I need only one fragment to be visible at time.
How on click button in activity which has this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.loyalty.MerchantsActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
         />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.loyalty.RewardsActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <com.touchmenotapps.widget.radialmenu.semicircularmenu.SemiCircularRadialMenu
        android:id="@+id/radial_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

to make that on click change which fragment is visible (only one is visible and use whole screen)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show one fragment at a time and also want many fragment to change, you have to create fragment dynamically in activity on a view click. use a xml like this one.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<!-- This will hold your fragment's view-->
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<!-- This part will be your activity specific --> 

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_fragmen1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_fragmen2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Here FrameLayout will be replaced with your Fragment that you want to show on Activity at that time, on Button click you can make this transition.
In activity to change the Fragment you have to write the following code.

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btn1, btn2;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.open_fragment1);
    btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.open_fragment2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
// I am assuming your fragment class is MerchantsActivity
           changeFragmentTo(new com.example.loyalty.MerchantsActivity());
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeFragmentTo(new com.example.loyalty.RewardsActivity());
        }
        });
    }
    public void changeFragmentTo(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_fragment, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

If you need to change another fragment to activity call the function `changeFragmnetTo(new NewFragment())`